# QGIS server legend does not show diagram colors

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, diagram, getlegendgraphic

I have a QGIS version 2.18.18 map with pie-chart diagrams. The pie-chart maps display correctly in both QGIS-desktop and QGIS-server versions. The pie-chart classes are correctly displayed in the QGIS desktop layers panel.

However, when I request the legend from QGIS server using a getlegendgraphic request, the pie-chart colors are not drawn.

The getlegendgraphic request is formatted as follows:
http://qgis-server-host/cgi-bin/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=myproject.qgs&service=WMS&version1.3.0&request=getlegendgraphic&layer=cbsbevolking2017legenda&format=image/png

**Images**
Map with diagrams:
[image: Map with diagrams]

Pie charts defined with Layer-Properties->Diagrams->Assigned Attributes:
[image: Layer diagram definition]

The legend in QGIS-desktop layers panel:
[image: QGIS legend in layers panel]

QGIS server getlegendgraphic response (missing colored classes):
[image: Server legend from getlegendgraphic request]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

problem (almost) solved in QGIS version 3.0.1

The layers panel in QGIS-desktop 3.0.1:
[image]

The getlegendgraphic from the QGIS-server 3.0.1:
[image]

For some reason the layer names are now duplicated. The getlegendgraphic request is now:

```
http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=myproject2.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&layer=kaarttotaal&format=image/png
```